# Rewriting core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/Product/CompareController.php

Tags: catalog, controllers, core

I'm trying to extend the "`Mage_Catalog_Product_CompareController`" class with my own class which is "`Invent_Catalog_Product_CompareController`" from the core.

But I can't seem to get the results that i am looking for. I suspect the problem on my config xml
here is my config.xml

```
<config>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <catalog>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <invent_catalog before="Mage_Catalog">Invent_Catalog</invent_catalog>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </catalog>
    </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

and here is my CompareController.php

```
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Catalog').DS.'CompareController.php');
class Invent_Catalog_Product_CompareController extends Mage_Catalog_Product_CompareController

 public function addAction()
    {
      //My Code goes here
   }
```

Comment: I assume that you close the `<config>` tag in `config.xml` (it is not in the code you provided) and also you have the module declaration file in `app/etc/modules` and you cleared the cache.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your `require_once` statement. It does not include the correct file.

```
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Catalog').DS.'CompareController.php');
```

Will include the file `Mage/Catalog/controllers/CompareController.php`
What you want is `Mage/Catalog/controllers/Product/CompareController.php`
For this use:

```
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Catalog').DS.'Product'.DS.'CompareController.php');
```